# Where can I find documentation for Android build options related to proguard

Tags: android, build, build-process, proguard

I have been doing a lot of work with the android build system and I ran into a situation that proguard was removing required classes causing a NoClassDefFoundError.  I could tell the class was not being found however it took me a while to figure out that proguard was messing up the classes that were build with my code.

I finally found that I could prevent proguard from running by adding `LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled` to the Android.mk file.

I was only able to do this because I happened to chance accross someone elses Android.mk file that did the same.

I have not been able to find any documentation for the following

```
LOCAL_PROGUARD_FLAGS
LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED
LOCAL_PROGUARD_FLAG_FILES
```

As best I can tell the typical usage of `LOCAL_PROGUARD_FLAGS` is to identify the location of the proguard configuration file used as follows:

```
LOCAL_PROGUARD_FLAGS := -include $(LOCAL_PATH)/proguard.flags
```

Problem is I cannot figure out how it differs from the `LOCAL_PROGUARD_FLAG_FILES` used as follows:

```
LOCAL_PROGUARD_FLAG_FILES := proguard.flags
```

The `LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED` can be used to disable proguard however other than the `disabled` option I don't know what else can be used with this option.

```
LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled
```

Does anyone know where I can find documentation (official or unofficial) for these build options?  Google does not seem to return anything useful for my searches.

Comment: Have you read the Proguard docs on the Android dev site? http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html In particular Configuring Proguard and the use of `-keep` to prevent it stripping out certain classes?

Comment: @Squonk Yes I have read the documents that you linked to.  Unfortunately those documents are out of date.  With the release of ADT 17 the way proguard is used changed. see: http://tools.android.com/recent/proguardimprovements .  None of these documents say anything about the three Android.mk build options I asked about originally.  I had to experiment to find a solution that worked.  It would have saved me hours if I could find some documentation.  Also It would help verify that my solution was the best solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I searched for that information also and stumbled upon this patch:

```
    Now the meaning of the LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED options:

    * full:
        Use the build system's default configurations:
        with shrink but no obfuscation or optimization,
        global proguard flags in build/core/proguard.flags
        are applied.
    * custom:
        The same as "full" except no aapt-generated resource-related
        proguard flags.
    * nosystem:
        Don't use any build system's default configurations; but
        aapt-generated proguard flags are still applied. You are
        responsible for any other flags.
    * disabled:
        Disable proguard.
    * obfuscation:
        The same as "full" but with obfuscation enabled.
    * optimization:
        The same as "full" but with optimization enabled.
    * no value (the default):
        The build system chooses the proper value: "full" if it's an
        app; "disabled" if it's a library.
```

Here is the link:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/7311a34%5E!/